# GHC warnings are suppressed unless intermediate files are deleted

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm compiling my program as: `ghc -Wall foo.hs`
and I get some helpful warnings:

```
foo.hs:14:1: Warning:
    Top-level binding with no type signature: main :: IO ()
```

Now, if I immediately re-run `ghc -Wall foo.hs`, I get no warnings. If I delete the intermediate files `foo.o` and `foo.hi`, then run `ghc -Wall foo.hs`, the warnings reappear.

Is this intended behaviour? Can I make it so warnings are always displayed without having to delete intermediate files?

Comment: Does `ghc` actually recompiles the files? I have the impression that `ghc` first checks the timestamp of `.o`, etc. If the `.o` exists and is younger than the codefile, then no compilation is done at all. So even the compiler is rather lazy :).

Comment: Good point - no, `ghc` actually didn't compile the files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results of compilation (`.hi` and `.o`) already exist then GHC will not recompile the `.hs`.  GHC only emits the warning when it compiles (or typechecks) the `.hs`.

Perhaps you could use `ghc -fforce-recomp foo.hs` to force recompiling.  (If you just want to typecheck then it's quicker to use`ghc -fforce-recomp -fno-code foo.hs` but there are some warnings that `-fno-code` doesn't catch.)